# Distance of the labels from the axis

Tags: pgfplots, baposter

I am a beginner with the package TikZ. I am using pgfplots to produce a very simple plot. The code I am using has been copied from an example found on the web, but my output is different from the example I saw.

This is the code:

```
\pgfplotsset{   width=0.45\linewidth,
             xmin=0,xmax=100,
             ymin=0,ymax=1,
             grid=major
            }
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xlabel=Percentage,
    ylabel=Accuracy]
    \addplot[smooth,mark=*,blue] plot coordinates {
    (11,0.6)
(15,    0.71)
(19,    0.7)
(25,    0.74)
(32,    0.73)
(40,    0.78)
(50,    0.81)
(51,    0.79)
(55,    0.79)
(56,    0.79)
(58,    0.77)
(61,    0.77)
(69,    0.77)
};
\addlegendentry{legend}
[...]
```

In the output the labels of the axis ticks are too close to the line. Is there any way to move the farther away? [I cannot post an image because my reputation is too low]

I have read the manual and checked other questions, but I cannot find the option/command I need to use.

Could you please help me?

---

While writing the minimal example as requested in the comments, I discovered that I see that problem only when the document class is `baposter`. With the `article` class it works ok.

The minimal working example with class `baposter` follows:

```
\documentclass[a0paper,portrait]{baposter}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

  \begin{poster}{
    grid=false, 
    colspacing=0.7em,
    eyecatcher=false, 
    bgColorOne=white,
    background=plain,
   } %poster
   % eyecatcher
   {

   }
   % title
   {
    TITLE
   }
   %Authors
   {
    AUTHORS
   }
   % Logo
   {

   }

  \headerbox{header}{name=header,column=0,row=0,span=4}{ 
    \pgfplotsset{width=0.45\linewidth,
             xmin=0,xmax=100,
             ymin=0,ymax=1,
             grid=major
            }
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[
        xlabel=p,
        ylabel=a]
        \addplot[smooth,mark=*,blue] plot coordinates {
            (11, 0.6)
            (15, 0.71)
            (19, 0.7)
            (25, 0.74)

        };
        \addlegendentry{legend}
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
} % headerbox

\end{poster}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi Antonio, welcome to the site! I can't reproduce this, unfortunately. Could you turn your code snippet into a complete minimal example document, so starting from `\documentclass` and including all the options that are necessary to reproduce the problem (and only those)?

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. I discovered that there is no problem when using the article class. I was using the class baposter: I posted a minimal example with that document class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because the `baposter` class puts all its contents into a `tikzpicture` with the option `inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt`, which is passed on to your `tikzpicture`, causing the tick label nodes to be printed without any padding. You can reset the padding by adding `inner sep=0.333em, outer sep=0.5\pgflinewidth` to your `tikzpicture` options (those are the default values):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a0paper,portrait]{baposter}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

  \begin{poster}{
    grid=false, 
    colspacing=0.7em,
    eyecatcher=false, 
    bgColorOne=white,
    background=plain,
   } %poster
   % eyecatcher
   {

   }
   % title
   {
    TITLE
   }
   %Authors
   {
    AUTHORS
   }
   % Logo
   {

   }

  \headerbox{header}{name=header,column=0,row=0,span=4}{ 
    \pgfplotsset{width=0.45\linewidth,
             xmin=0,xmax=100,
             ymin=0,ymax=1,
             grid=major
            }
    \begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0.3333em, outer sep=0.5\pgflinewidth]
      \begin{axis}[
        xlabel=p,
        ylabel=a]
        \addplot[smooth,mark=*,blue] plot coordinates {
            (11, 0.6)
            (15, 0.71)
            (19, 0.7)
            (25, 0.74)

        };
        \addlegendentry{legend}
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
} % headerbox

\end{poster}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Indeed, it is the first time I am using baposter and tikz.

Answer (score 1):

You could use nodes instaed of xlabel and ylabel. You can place the nodes where you want by defining the right position.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks, arrows, shapes, backgrounds, shadows, positioning, calc, fit}

\begin{document}


\pgfplotsset{   width=0.45\linewidth,
             xmin=0,xmax=100,
             ymin=0,ymax=1,
             grid=major
            }
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    %xlabel=Percentage,
    %ylabel=Accuracy
        ]
    \addplot[smooth,mark=*,blue] plot coordinates {
    (11,0.6)
(15,    0.71)
(19,    0.7)
(25,    0.74)
(32,    0.73)
(40,    0.78)
(50,    0.81)
(51,    0.79)
(55,    0.79)
(56,    0.79)
(58,    0.77)
(61,    0.77)
(69,    0.77)
};

\end{axis}

\node at (1.5cm,-0.8cm) {Percentage};
\node at (-1cm,1.5cm) [rotate=90, anchor=base] {Acccuracy};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```